# Pause/user input (warndlg) issue in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

Prior to saving a file I wish to have a Warning Dialog. In the script below there is no stop for pressing the warndlg OK and the script moves automatically continue to the uiputfile. How can I pause between them/enforce user to press the OK before the uiputfile?

Script:

```
warndlg('May take time due to image size')
[file,path] = uiputfile('*.tif', 'Save As');
if file == 0
  return;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [uiwait](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html) function:

```
uiwait(warndlg('May take time due to image size'))
```

It will block the execution of your script until the `OK` button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either set the `createmode` option of the [`warndlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warndlg.html) to `'modal'`:

```
warndlg('May take time due to image size', 'Warning!', 'modal');
```

or pass the `warndlg` handle to the [`uiwait`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html) function to pause continuation of the program until the warning dialog is closed:

```
hWarn = warndlg('May take time due to image size');
uiwait(hWarn);
```